# Why does not covariance of interface work in constraints?

Tags: c#

If a class satisfies a covariant interface with a derived class as type parameter, why is that not enough to satisfy a constraint for the same interface with the base class as type parameter?

Given the following code

```
public interface ICovariantInterface<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Base { public int Value { get; set; } }

public class Sub : Base { public int OtherValue { get; set; } }

public class A : ICovariantInterface<Sub>
{
    Sub _sub = new Sub { Value = 1, OtherValue = 2 };
    public Sub Value { get { return _sub; } }
}

public class B : A
{
    ICovariantInterface<Base> MeAsInterface { get { return this; } }
}

public interface OtherInterface : ICovariantInterface<Base>
{ int ThirdValue { get; } }

public class C : A, OtherInterface
{
    ICovariantInterface<Base> MeAsInterface { get { return this; } }
    public int ThirdValue { get { return 2; } }
}
```

Class B works fine - since A satisfies the covariant interface ICovariantInterface with type parameter Sub, it can immediately be converted to the same interface with type parameter Base - but C fails to compile, with error

> 'CovarianceTest.C' does not implement interface member 'CovarianceTest.ICovariantInterface.Value'. 'CovarianceTest.A.Value' cannot implement 'CovarianceTest.ICovariantInterface.Value' because it does not have the matching return type of 'CovarianceTest.Base'.

How can C fail to satisfy the constraint when it can immediately be converted to the interface specified in the constraint?

This problem has made it quite difficult for me to take full advantage of the possibilites offered by covariance.

Comment: When inheriting from `A` you have implemented `Sub Value` property. By specifying `OtherInterface` you have to implement `Base Value` property. Those aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariance (and contravariance) establish rules for *consuming* types with type parameters marked with `out` (or `in`), in that, if you have an *instance* of a particular type certain implicit conversions are available to you, as the consumer.

In your example, `B` is *consuming* an instance of `A` (that happens to be itself, but need not have been) at the point at which your allowed cast occurs.

But in your `C` example, you're attempting to *implement* an interface. Covariance and Contravariance don't apply here - if the interface states that a method returns a `T` then the implementation has to provide a method that returns *exactly* the type substituted for `T`.